# Stack push(pop()*pop()) explanation

Tags: stack

[image: stack]
in d) example image is showing stack after function push(pop()*pop()) that is used on state that is shown in picture c). can someone explain to me why is number 2,5 still there? and how that push pop pop function works?

Comment: It seems to me that 2.5 shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure (without knowing what's written) that what the picture illustrates is that there's no need to "physically remove" the 2.5 from the stack, but that only the stack head pointer ("vrh"?) is adjusted. Whenever something new is pushed onto the stack, the 2.5 will simply be overwritten.

Probably, the reason 2.5 is "starred" is precisely to indicate that, while it's there, it no longer matters for the purpose of any operations on the stack. Technically, the 10 wasn't removed by its corresponding `pop` call either, but was simply overwritten when the 25 was `push`ed.

Of course, this only illustrates the details of a particular implementation of a stack structure. It would be just as valid for an implementation to purge the 2.5 -- the user of the implementation would have no way to tell the difference anyway.

Comment: i think you answered my question. thank you.. you are right... that is only there to show us that 2,5 doesent exisist anymore but that confused me... so just to be clear push(pop*pop) does this: takes nubmer 10,takes number 2,5... multiple them 10*2,5=25 and pushes that value in stack,am i right?

Comment: That is mostly right, though to be exact, it would be more correct to say that it first takes the number 2.5 and *then* the number 10.

Comment: yes yes i meant that... stack takes first number. First in last out. thank you so much for your help!